# Could not find com.google.flatbuffers:flatbuffers-java:x.x.x

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

After I migrated to the androidx dependencies, an activity generated this message

Answer (score 1):

Adding **mavenCentral()** to the repositories in your *build.gradle* will resolve the problem.